# fullpage.js moveTo() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm trying to use the [moveTo()](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#movetosection-slide) function in **fullpage.js** that allows me to navigate to a particular section/slide, which looks like this:

```
/*Scrolling to the section with the anchor link `firstSlide` and to the 2nd Slide */
$.fn.fullpage.moveTo('firstSlide', 2);
```

I'm trying to use this within the `afterSlideLoad()` function, in an attempt to automatically cycle through the slides. my code looks like this:

```
 $.fn.fullpage({
     anchors: ['home', 'gallery'],
     afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
         if (anchorLink == 'gallery') {
             if (slideIndex == 11) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      moveTo(2,0);
                  }, 1000);
             } else {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      moveTo(2, slideIndex + 1);
                  }, 1000);
             }
         }
     });
```

Which doesn't appear to do anything, I've also tried `moveTo('gallery', 1);`

any suggestions with where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation you are linking](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#movetosection-slide), the function must be called like this:

```
$.fn.fullpage.moveTo('firstSlide', 2);
```

And not like you are doing it:

```
moveTo('firstSlide', 2);
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/15/)

Comment: believe it or not i thought i had tried that also, but i think i must have called it like this $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(firstSlide, 2); thank you